# mySQL procedure does not commit on commit statement

Tags: mysql, transactions, handler, commit, procedure

This is my code:

BEGIN
DECLARE _cnt      INT;
DECLARE  i        INT DEFAULT 0 ;
DECLARE  j        INT DEFAULT 0 ;
DECLARE _FIPSAPNCombo     VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE _prv_FIPSAPNCombo VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE _Rollyear         INT DEFAULT 2000;
DECLARE _first_Rollyear   INT DEFAULT 2000;
DECLARE eof               boolean default FALSE;
DECLARE _AvTotal  INT;
DECLARE _prv_AvTotal INT default 0;
DECLARE _YOY_PCT  INT;
DECLARE _YOY_USD  INT;
DECLARE _in_pct   INT;
DECLARE _in_usd   INT;
DECLARE _last     INT;
DECLARE _id       INT;
DECLARE _idx      INT;
DECLARE _prv_id   INT;

DECLARE get_FIPSAPNCombo CURSOR
FOR
SELECT 0, '0', 2000, 1
UNION
SELECT id, FIPSAPNCombo, rollyear, AvTotal
FROM   AvHistory_06037  AS h
WHERE  substr(h.FIPSAPNCombo,1,8) = _in_FIPSAPNCombo_8
AND    h.AvTotal > 0
ORDER  BY 2, 3
;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
FOR NOT FOUND
SET eof = TRUE;

SELECT YOY_PCT, YOY_USD INTO _in_pct, _in_usd FROM AlertSearches WHERE id = _in_AlertSearchesID;
START TRANSACTION;
OPEN get_FIPSAPNCombo;
doit: LOOP
fetch get_FIPSAPNCombo INTO _id, _FIPSAPNCombo, _Rollyear, _AvTotal;
SET _YOY_USD = _AvTotal - _prv_AvTotal;
SET _YOY_PCT = ROUND((((_AvTotal - _prv_AvTotal) / _prv_AvTotal) * 100),0);
IF eof = TRUE THEN
LEAVE doit;
END IF;
IF _FIPSAPNCombo != _prv_FIPSAPNCombo THEN SET _first_Rollyear = _Rollyear; ELSE SET _first_Rollyear = '2000'; END IF;
IF _YOY_PCT >= _in_pct AND _YOY_USD >= _in_usd and _Rollyear != _first_Rollyear THEN
BEGIN
DELETE FROM AvHistoryAlerts WHERE FIPSAPNCombo = _FIPSAPNCombo AND AlertSearchesID = _in_AlertSearchesID;
INSERT INTO AvHistoryAlerts VALUES (_id, _FIPSAPNCombo, '06037', _Rollyear, _AvTotal, _YOY_PCT, _YOY_USD, _prv_id, _prv_AvTotal, _in_AlertSearchesID);
UPDATE AvHistory SET CausalTransfer =  NULL   WHERE FIPSAPNCombo = _FIPSAPNCombo;
UPDATE AvHistory SET CausalTransfer = 'Green' WHERE id           = _id;
SET  i  =  i  + 1;
IF mod(i,1000) = 0 THEN insert into error_log VALUES (concat(_in_FIPSAPNCombo_8, ' > calc_YOY_increase i  = ', i, ' ',now())); COMMIT;   START TRANSACTION; END IF;
END;
END IF;
SET _prv_FIPSAPNCombo = _FIPSAPNCombo;
SET _prv_AvTotal      = _AvTotal;
SET _prv_id           = _id;
SET eof = FALSE;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
CLOSE get_FIPSAPNCombo;

END

I thought that the procedure would commit every 1000 records processed and that this would be reflected in the error_log table in real time.

But, the data is only available after the procedure finishes completely and then all the records show up all at once in the error_log table.

That, by itself, is not the issue: what I am concerned about is the the procedure seems to dwell on "waiting for handler commit" for a long time at the end of the procedure.

So, I'm not sure what's going on: is it storing everything in memory or in a temp table or file and then needs a lot if time for cleanup?

I thought that a commit would clear all that... but it does not seem to commit until the end of the whole procedure

Any ideas?

Comment: What db engine are you using (myisam,innodb etc)

Comment: @p-salmon innodb

Comment: @p-salmon I input the whole procedure.